# Existence of Solution, System of Equations

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, functional-equations

Suppose $P(\lambda, i)$ is the probability that a Poisson random variable with average $\lambda$ is equal to $i$, i.e. $\frac{\lambda^i}{e^{\lambda}i!}$

I think the following system of equations always has solution in $x$ and $y$, non-negative real numbers, for any $\alpha>0$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}_+$

\begin{cases}
\alpha=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(x, i)\cdot P(y, k+i)  \\
\alpha=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(x, i)\cdot P(y, k+i+1)
\end{cases}

where the necessary condition $\alpha\leq P(k+1, k+1)$ holds. It is easy to prove that this is indeed a necessary condition, equivalent to the condition that $\alpha=P(\lambda,k+1)$ has a solution. It is also easy to see that solution $y$ of the system is smaller or equal to $\lambda$, the largest solution to the equation $\alpha=P(\lambda,k+1)$. Experiments show that for each fixed $\alpha$ and $k$, there is a solution, but I did not manage to prove it analytically.

Is there any analogue for mean value theorem for multidimensional functions?
Any suggestion for the proof directions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $a:=\alpha$ and 
\begin{equation*}
 F_k(x,y):=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!}\frac{y^{k+j}}{(k+j)!}\,e^{-x-y},
\end{equation*}
assuming the standard convention $0^0:=1$. 
We have to consider the existence of a solution in $x$ and $y$ of the system 
\begin{equation*}
 a=F_k(x,y)=F_{k+1}(x,y). \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
We shall prove the following.

> **Theorem 1.** Take any natural $k$ and any 
>   \begin{equation*}
>  a\in(0,a_k],\quad\text{where}\quad a_k:=\sup_{x,y\ge0}F_{k+1}(x,y). \tag{1.5}
> \end{equation*}
>   Then the system (1) has a solution $x,y\ge0$.

*Remark 1.* Since $F_k>0$, the condition $a\in(0,a_k]$ is obviously necessary in Theorem 1.

*Proof of Theorem 1.* Note that $F_k(x,y)\ge0$ for any real $x,y\ge0$ and $F_k(x,y)$ is continuous in real $x,y\ge0$. The crucial observation is the identity 
\begin{equation*}
 \partial_y F_{k+1}(x,y)=F_k(x,y)-F_{k+1}(x,y) \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
for real $x,y$.

Next, fix for a moment any real $x\ge0$. Then $F_{k+1}(x,0)=0$ and, by dominated convergence, $F_{k+1}(x,\infty-)=0$. So, $F_{k+1}(x,y)$ attains its maximum in $y$ at some real point $y=y_x\ge0$. At this point, we have $\partial_y F_{k+1}(x,y)=0$. So, by (2), 
\begin{equation*}
 F_k(x,y_x)=F_{k+1}(x,y_x)=\max_{y\ge0}F_{k+1}(x,y)=:M_{k+1}(x), \tag{3} 
\end{equation*}
for all real $x\ge0$.

Next, 
\begin{align*}
 M_k(x)&\le\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!}\max_{y\ge0}\frac{y^{k+j}}{(k+j)!}\,e^{-x-y} \\ 
 &=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!}e^{-x}\frac{(k+j)^{k+j}}{(k+j)!}\,e^{-k-j} \tag{4} \\ 
 &\ll\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!}e^{-x}\frac1{\sqrt{k+j}}=E\frac1{\sqrt{k+\Pi_x}}
 \underset{x\to\infty}\longrightarrow0 
\end{align*}
by dominated convergence and because $\Pi_x\underset{x\to\infty}\longrightarrow\infty$ in probability, where $\Pi_x$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $x$. So,
$M_k(\infty-)=0$. It is also not hard to see that 
$F_k(x,y)$ is continuous in real $x\ge0$ uniformly in real $y\ge0$ (see the Appendix), so that $M_k(x)$ is continuous in $x\ge0$. So, $M_{k+1}(x)$ attains its maximum in $x\ge0$ (equal $a_k$, by (1.5)) and takes all values in the interval $(0,a_k]$. Now Theorem 1 follows by (3). $\qquad\Box$

**Appendix.** Similarly to (2), 
\begin{equation*}
 \partial_x F_k(x,y)=F_{k+1}(x,y)-F_k(x,y). 
\end{equation*}
for real $x,y$. Therefore and because $0\le F_k\le1$, we have $|\partial_x F_k(x,y)|\le1$ for real $x,y$, so that $F_k(x,y)$ is indeed continuous in real $x\ge0$ uniformly in real $y\ge0$.

**Added:** Let us now show that 
\begin{equation*}
 a_k=c_{k+1},\quad\text{where}\quad c_k:=\frac{k^k}{k!}\,e^{-k}
 \sim\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi k}}   
\end{equation*}
as $k\to\infty$. To this end, note first that 
\begin{equation*}
 c_{k+1}/c_k=(1+1/k)^k/e<1,
\end{equation*}
and so, $c_k$ is decreasing in $k$. 
So, recalling (4), we have 
\begin{equation*}
 M_k(x)\le\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!}e^{-x}\,c_{k+j}
 \le\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!}e^{-x}\,c_k=c_k=M_k(0). 
\end{equation*}
Thus, in view of (1.5) and (2), 
\begin{equation*}
 a_k=\max_{x\ge0}M_{k+1}(x)=M_{k+1}(0)=c_{k+1}, 
\end{equation*}
as desired.

In particular, for $k=0,1,2,3$ the values of $a_k$ are $\approx0.367879, 0.270671, 0.224042$.

Comment: I have added Remark 2 concerning the values of $a_k$.

Comment: The proof of $a_k=P(k+1,k+1)$ is very easy, if $\alpha>P(k+1,k+1)$ then it implies $\alpha>P(\lambda, k+1)$ for each $\lambda$, since $P(\lambda,k+1)$ is maximized for $\lambda=k+1$. On the other hand, by induction we can prove that $\alpha>P(\lambda,k+1+i)$ for any $i>0$ and $\lambda$, therefore the second equation does not have a solution!

Comment: @Tina : I am afraid I don't understand your comment: (i) So, what if $\alpha>P(\lambda,k+1)$? What does this imply? (ii) What is your $\alpha$ in the inequality $\alpha>P(\lambda,k+1+i)$? (iii) How do you prove this inequality? (iv) What does this latter inequality imply?

Comment: (i) if $\alpha>P(\lambda, k+1)$ for any $\lambda$ this implies that $\alpha>P(\lambda,k+2)$ or for any $i>0$, $\alpha>P(\lambda,k+1+i)$. (ii) $\alpha$ is the parameter from the system of equations. (iii) proof is by induction, if $\alpha>P(\lambda,k+1)$, this means $\alpha\cdot e^{\lambda} - \frac{\lambda^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}>0$, then $\alpha\cdot e^{\lambda} - \frac{\lambda^{k+2}}{(k+2)!}>0$, since the latter holds for $\lambda=0$ and its derivative is the former, always positive. (iv) this implies that the second inequality of the system is not solvable, since $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(x,i)=1$.

Comment: @Tina : I am sorry, I still don't understand your comment.

Comment: I have now added a proof of the previously conjectured explicit, and quite simple, expression for the threshold value $a_k$.

Answer (score 2):

The sums over $P(\lambda,i)=\frac{\lambda^i}{e^{\lambda}i!}$ are evaluated in terms of a Bessel function as
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(x, i)\cdot P(y, k+i)=y^k e^{-x-y} \left(xy\right)^{-k/2} I_k\left(2 \sqrt{xy}\right)$$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(x, i)\cdot P(y, k+i+1)=(y/x)^{1/2}\,y^{k} e^{-x-y} \left(xy\right)^{-k/2} I_{k+1}\left(2 \sqrt{xy}\right)$$
for any positive integer $k$ these two expressions should be equal for some $x,y>0$. (For $x=y=0$ both expressions are identically zero.) So the function
$$F_k(x,y)=\sqrt{x}\, I_k\left(2 \sqrt{xy}\right)-\sqrt{y} \,I_{k+1}\left(2 \sqrt{xy}\right)$$
should pass through zero in the quadrant $x,y>0$ for any positive integer $k$.

For large $z=2\sqrt{xy}$ both Bessel functions $I_k(z)$ and $I_{k+1}(z)$ grow as $(2\pi z)^{-1/2}e^z$, so by making $x$ much larger than $y$ the function $F_k(x,y)$ is positive and by making $y$ much larger than $x$ it is negative, hence it must go through zero when $x\approx y$.

---

I had not appreciated that $\alpha$ is fixed from the beginning like $k$, not a variable like $x$ and $y$. So we also need to show that $x\approx y\gg 1$ allows the sum to reach any $\alpha>0$, so
$$\alpha=e^{-2x}  I_k\left(2x\right)\approx (4\pi x)^{-1/2},\;\;x\gg 1.$$
This is possible only for $\alpha\ll 1$. The OP lists as necessary condition $\alpha\leq P(k+1,k+1)$, it is not clear to me this is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you! But I do not understand why both terms are equal to $\alpha$?

Comment: ah wait, $\alpha$ is fixed from the beginning like $k$ and not a variable like $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes, it is a fixed parameter of the system, like $k$. We should somehow use the necessary condition from the statement.